# QTreeWidget select first item

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am making a `QTreeWidget` from a XML file. The XML looks like below and I want to make a tree of the names:

```
<root>
    <f name='foo'>bar
        <f name='foo2'>baz</f>
    </f>
</root>
```

At the moment I am using the following code to do so *(somewhat simplified code)*:

```
import lxml.etree as et

#...

self.xml = et.XML(filters.filtersxml)
self.tree_widget = QTreeWidget(parent)

def add_items(parent, xmlroot):
    for i in xmlroot.getchildren():
        item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [i.get('name')])
        if len(i.getchildren()) != 0:
            add_items(item, i)

add_items(self.tree_widget, self.xml)
```

I actually have two questions about this:

1. **Main question:** Is there some way to select the first item in the tree, foo in this case. I tried to do something with `setCurrentItem()` and `setCurrentIndex()`, but couldn't get it to work. I have googled a bit about it, but all the solutions that I found work with models.
2. (Optional) Is this recursive function a good approach to do this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recursive is good, would keep it that way, and in answer to your main question just do:

```
# after all your code
add_items(self.tree_widget, self.xml)

# select the root item
self.tree_widget.setCurrentItem(self.tree_widget.topLevelItem(0))
```

You just have to make sure that the item has already been added to the tree when you call setCurrentItem - otherwise it won't really work.  Some methods require the item to already be associated to a tree (like setExpanded and setSelected)

**Edit**

To build up recursively without affecting the tree, you can do:

```
import lxml.etree as et

#...

self.xml = et.XML(filters.filtersxml)
self.tree_widget = QTreeWidget(parent)

def add_items(parent, xmlroot):
    output = []
    for i in xmlroot.getchildren():
        item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [i.get('name')])
        output.append(item)
        if len(i.getchildren()) != 0:
            add_items(item, i)
    return output

items = add_items(None, self.xml)
self.tree_widget.addTopLevelItems(items)
self.tree_widget.setCurrentItem(items[0])
```

**Edit 2: Loading all at once**

And to go a bit further down the rabbit hole, the way that I would personally do this to minimize unnecessary calls and lists as much as possible would be to build the loop the children only once:

```
import lxml.etree as et

#...

self.xml = et.XML(filters.filtersxml)
self.tree_widget = QTreeWidget(parent)

def create_item(parent, xmlroot):
    item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [xmlroot.get('name')])
    for xmlchild in xmlroot.getchildren():
       create_item(item, xmlchild)
    return item

items = [create_item(None, xmlchild) for xmlchild in self.xml.getchildren()]
self.tree_widget.addTopLevelItems(items)
if ( items ):
    self.tree_widget.setCurrentItem(items[0])
```

**Edit 3: Loading dynamically**

And since it was brought up...a way to dynamically load the children would be to store each level and load them after being expanded:

```
import lxml.etree as et
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTreeWidgetItem

# ...    

class XmlTreeWidgetItem(QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __init__( self, parent, xmlitem ):
        super(MyTreeWidgetItem, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setText(0, xmlitem.get('name'))
        self.setChildIndicatorPolicy(self.ShowIndicator)

        self._xmlitem = xmlitem
        self._loaded = False

    def loadChildren( self ):
        if ( self._loaded ):
            return

        self._loaded = True
        self.setChildIndicatorPolicy(self.DontShowIndicatorWhenChildless)
        for xmlchild in self._xmlitem.getchildren():
            XmlTreeWidgetItem(self, xmlchild)

# ...

class SomeClass(QWidget):
    def __init__( self, parent = None ):
        super(SomeClass, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tree_widget = QTreeWidget(parent)

        xml = et.XML(filters.filtersxml)
        items = [XmlTreeWidgetItem(None, xchild) for xchild in xml.getchildren()]
        self.tree_widget.addTopLevelItems(items)
        if ( items ):
            self.tree_widget.setCurrentItem(items[0])

        # create connections
        self.tree_widget.itemExpanded.connect(self.loadItem)

    def loadItem( self, item ):
        item.loadChildren()
```

Comment: I think normally you would build up the items outside the tree, and then take either a single root item (if thats how its being designed) or the list of top level items and do: `insertTopLevelItem` or `insertTopLevelItems`

Comment: yea, thats usually the way I do it too...not really sure which is better or faster, so I'll say both are viable.  I would also recommend sandwiching any modifications to a tree widget like this within a blockSignals(True/False) and setUpdatesEnabled(False/True) call as well.

Comment: Well I think if you make sure to build up your item structure first, and then finally add it into the tree with a single call, you won't have to worry about that. But thats a good point for when you are adding and removing items randomly in a loop

Comment: @jdi is it only better to build the items outside the tree because of possible error that you have to deal with, or are there other reasons too. Because I assume that you would built up the items with a similar function with an .append() instead of creating the item, right? Or do you built up the items without recursion somehow? (as you can see I am quite a recursion and qt noob :))

Comment: The benefit of building them up outside is that the tree will not constantly have to fire events/signals and react to items being added. Its not really a case of error prevention. Eric was suggesting blocking the signals around the operation, but you can avoid the need by just appending parent -> child -> child outside, and adding the final top level item to the table once.

Comment: @jdi. What events/signals are you thinking of? I have never personally encountered problems with building trees in place. I suppose there are potential performance issues if the tree is very large and sorting is enabled - but of course it can easily be temporarily disabled if necessary.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do - sometimes I need to be able to reference an item's tree widget during creation so I add them to the tree during creation vs. after the fact, in which case I block the signals from being sent.  Most of the time I agree with jdi though, building up outside the tree and then adding the top level items at the end is the simplest way to go.  I edited the answer with the way to do it recursively without assigning to the tree first.

Comment: Nice update. I was thinking if there was a modification that could be done so that you don't have to do a bunch of wasted list appends for the entire child hierarchy that is never used. Its only being used to return the root items. Maybe a check on `if parent is None`?

Comment: Well, arguably the way I would do this in general would be to create 1 head (the xml root) and add that, but I was trying to keep the code as similar to the original as possible...one more update coming up ;-)

Comment: @EricHulser. Actually, I think the reason why I usually build trees in place, is that I usually try to grow the tree dynamically by using the `expanded` signal to build sub-trees. That way, it's not necessary to build the entire tree first, and so it can be loaded more efficiently.

Comment: @ekhumoro - yea, true, I do that a lot too - especially if I'm querying for child data or anything like that.  Load one layer at a time, set its ChildIndicator and load children later...but that gets to be a much more complex example ;-)

Comment: I like that last example. +1 . And also, good points on the dynamically expanding children. That would come into play if they are expensive to fetch, or need to be accurate at the moment they are loaded. Nice conversation BTW :-)

Comment: yea, this was a good question and topic.  Cheers guys.  I just updated the answer again with an example of dynamic loading without recursion.

Comment: WOW! Well, that escalated quickly :). @EricHulser, if I could upvote an answer multiple times I would, this is by far the most complete answer I've ever gotten. These are really good examples, I had no idea that there were so many ways to do this, especially the last example would have never crossed my mind.

Comment: btw, in your second example it should be `item = QTreeWidgetItem(parent, [xmlroot.get('name')])`, the second arg is a list of strings for each column. (But that's just nitpicking, you're still awesome)

Comment: Ah yes, cheers...I didn't really test any of the code so there may be typos here and there...but thanks and I'm glad to help :-)

Comment: @EricHulser, I apologize to resurrect this old thread.. but what about using ``lxml.objectify``?